# Property 'createGame$' does not exist on 'GameService'

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created a `GameService` class that implements the `ServiceInterface`:

```
export interface ServiceInterface {
  emitter$;
  actions: any[];
  [action: string]: any;
}

export class GameService implements ServiceInterface {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.actions = [
      { name: 'createGame$', handler: this.createGame.bind(this) }
    ];
    this.registerActions();
  }

  registerActions() {
    // for each action, create action subject and subscribe a handler
    if (this.actions) {
      for (let action of this.actions) {
        this[action.name] = new Subject();
        this[action.name].subscribe(action.handler);
      }
    }
  }
```

The `GameService` dynamically adds properties, in this case `this.createGame$`. But I'm getting the error:

```
Property 'createGame$' does not exist on 'GameService'
```

I thought that `[action: string]: any;` on the interface would allow me to dynamically add properties - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dynamic properties aren't known at compile-time

Comment: Right, so what do people generally do here - somehow suppress the warnings?

Comment: Use `gameService['createGame$'].doSomething()`. Not very pretty. I would just forget the dynamic property, at least in this case. I don't see why you would even want to do this.

Comment: Or `(<any>gameService).createGame$` would actually work

Comment: Or `this['createGame$']` or `(<any>this).createGame$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you create `actions`, you're trying to bind `createGame` to an action that doesn't yet exist

```
this.actions = [
    { name: 'createGame$', handler: this.createGame.bind(this) }
];
```

I would create the handlers in `registerActions` instead since at that point you have a reference to the current `action`

```
 constructor(){
    this.actions = [
        {name:'createGame$', handler:null}
     ];
     this.registerActions();
 }

 registerActions(){
    //current class instance. includes createGame$ property
    console.log('registerActions(): ', this); 

     if(this.actions){
        for (let action of this.actions) {
            //set handler here instead of constructor in order to bind
            // to current action
            action.handler = this.createGame.bind(action); 

             this[action.name] = new Subject();
             this[action.name].subscribe(action.handler);
         }
     }
 }

 createGame(){
    // here, 'this' is the current action
    console.log('createGame(): ', this);
 }
```

[**plunker demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ngw22x8PThmRKIQRgIr2?p=preview)